# Drawing/manipulate a quadrilateral vector on an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vector, raphael

I am trying to develop a system that will render a preview of a what a product might look like with embossing.

In order to do this, I am essentially going to composite two images together.  In order to do this correctly, I am building a system using mainly JavaScript that allows a background image to be chosen. Someone will then draw a quadrilateral on this image that represents the correct proportions of the composite image.

This image, which is rectangular, will be distorted to match the four coordinates that comprise this quadrilateral using Imagick.

The piece I'm a little hazy on is the JavaScript.  It doesn't need to support multiple browsers, Webkit or FF is fine.

At a minimum, it should put a rectangular shape comprised of four points.  These points can then be manipulated at will and a line would be drawn between the points to help the user visualize the effect.

This is a crude description, but the best I have.  In a perfect world, I'd love to do something similar to [this](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) , but with more flexibility. http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#aspect-ratio is also a good example of something similar to what I'm envisioning, but with less constrained transformations.

I've investigated `Raphael.js`, which looks promising too but I'm weary of reinventing the wheel.

Any thoughts? Am I missing any obvious JavaScript libraries/implementations that might be useful here?

**EDIT: I ended up using Flash and this AS3 class: http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage
It was a pain, but I got it working.  I'm leaving this up in case someone wants to opine on a javascript technique.**